# A Pythonic way to delete older logfiles

Tags: python

I'm just cleaning log files greater than 50 (by oldest first). This is the only thing I've been able to come up with and I feel like there is a better way to do this.  I'm currently getting a pylint warning using the lambda on `get_time`.

```
def clean_logs():
    log_path = "Runtime/logs/"
    max_log_files = 50

    def sorted_log_list(path):
        get_time = lambda f: os.stat(os.path.join(path, f)).st_mtime
        return list(sorted(os.listdir(path), key=get_time))

    del_list = sorted_log_list(log_path)[0:(len(sorted_log_list(log_path)) - max_log_files)]

    for x in del_list:
        pathlib.Path(pathlib.Path(log_path).resolve() / x).unlink(missing_ok=True)


clean_logs()
```

Comment: Which OS?  Command line tools might be better suited for this task. If you have access to GNU tools (or the like) the `find` command with args would be a one liner.

Comment: I'm on Windows, but I'd really like to do this with python. I have already done it in the above code, it does work, but it's a pep error, plus I'd like to know if there was a shorter/cleaner way to do this.

Comment: My apologies on the delay in posting an answer. Please see the simplified and efficient approach below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two simplified solutions below are used to accomplish different tasks, so included both for flexibility. Obviously, you can wrap this in a function if you like.

Both code examples breaks down into the following steps:

- Set the date delta (as an epoch reference) for `mtime` comparison as, N days prior to today.
- Collect the full path to all files matching a given extension.
- Create a generator (or list) to hold the files to be deleted, using `mtime` as a reference.
- Iterate the results and delete all applicable files.

---

#### Removing log files older than (n) days:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime as dt
from glob import glob

# Setup
path = '/tmp/logs/'
days = 5
ndays = dt.now().timestamp() - days * 86400

# Collect all files.
files = glob(os.path.join(path, '*.sql.gz'))
# Choose files to be deleted.
to_delete = (f for f in files if os.stat(f).st_mtime < ndays)

# Delete files older than (n) days.
for f in to_delete:
    os.remove(f)
```

---

#### Keeping the (n) latest log files

To keep the (n) latest log files, simply replace the `to_delete` definition above with:

```
n = 50
to_delete = sorted(files, key=lambda x: os.stat(x).st_mtime)[:len(files)-n]
```

Comment: I used the 2nd way, since that was what I needed, it was very easy to understand use. Also less code + more efficient then the way I was doing it. I really appreciate the response and help!!

I really like how you showed both methods as well!